# Python - Search in source of a website and print out the website when a word its found

Tags: python, url

I am trying to create a python script(but without results untill now) to return from a list of urls the urls that contain in source a word, in my case are two types of urls containing some of them

```
"var dle_act_lang   = ["Yes", "No", "Enter", "Cancel", "Save"];"
```

and some of them:

```
"var dle_act_lang   = ["Да", "Нет", "Ввод", "Отмена", "Сохранить"];"
```

**The two lines are the words that i am searching for, not separate ones**

Please can someone help me to create this script? All i want is to sort these urls by these two code lines!

Comment: This is not Python. Python does not have a `var` keyword, or semicolons. Are you sure you're not looking for an answer in JavaScript or some other language?

Comment: Now you've put the whole line of JavaScript (or whatever it is) inside a string. So does that mean you're trying to search for any pages that have exactly that line of JavaScript in them? Because if so, it's a bit simpler.

Comment: @abarnert yes, this is what im trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a bunch of URLs and you want to get the source for the pages they refer to:

```
urls = ['http://example.com/foo', 'http://example.com/bar']
pages = {url: urllib2.urlopen(url).read() for url in urls}
```

Now, you want to find out which of them contains any word from `dle_act_lang`. One way to do that is to convert everything to `set`s and just use set intersection:

```
pagesets = {url: set(page.split()) for url, page in pages.iteritems()}
wordset = set(dle_act_lang)

matching_urls = [url for url, pageset in pagesets.iteritems() if wordset & pageset]
```

That's it.

However, while this answers the question you start off with, by the end of the question you seem to be asking for something completely different: "All i want is to sort these urls by these two code lines!" I don't know what you mean by "sort… by these two code lines", but whatever you mean, there's no sorting going on in what you asked for, or in this code.

---

From your later edit, it looks like you may be searching for a line of JavaScript code, like this:

```
"var dle_act_lang   = ["Yes", "No", "Enter", "Cancel", "Save"];"
```

So, don't need to create a `wordset` out of that and do `wordset & pageset`; just leave the JS code and the pages as pain old strings and use the `in` operator:

```
urls = ['http://example.com/foo', 'http://example.com/bar']
pages = {url: urllib2.urlopen(url).read() for url in urls}
jscode = '''"var dle_act_lang   = ["Yes", "No", "Enter", "Cancel", "Save"];"'''
matching_urls = [url for url, pages in pages.iteritems() if jscode in page]
```

---

However, if these are actually complete lines, and there are a whole lot of them, instead of repeating that for each line of code you want to search for, you might want to use `set`s of *lines* instead of *words*, and go back to something like the first example I gave:

```
urls = ['http://example.com/foo', 'http://example.com/bar']
pages = {url: urllib2.urlopen(url).read() for url in urls}
pagesets = {url: set(line.strip() for line in page.split('\n')) 
            for url, page in pages.iteritems()}
jscodeset = {'''"var dle_act_lang   = ["Yes", "No", "Enter", "Cancel", "Save"];"''',
             '''"var dle_act_lang   = ["Да", "Нет", "Ввод", "Отмена", "Сохранить"];"''']}
matching_urls = [url for url, pageset in pagesets.iteritems() if wordset & pageset]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urls = ['http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com', 'http://facebook.com', 'http://turnplay.com']
words = ['book', 'play']

matches = []

for url in urls:
   for word in words:
      if word in url:
         matches.append(url)

print matches  # <== ['http://facebook.com', 'http://turnplay.com']
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to match the text of the URLs. First, he says "contain in source", presumably meaning the source of the page the URL is pointing to. And, while that may be ambiguous, he's also searching for things like `"Yes"`, which are unlikely to appear in a URL but very likely to appear on a web page.

Comment: Yes, the code from you "dlink" is searching only in the link! but i need to search in source code and after that to return the link